# Handlebars templatig: Difference between empty list and list not given

Tags: handlebars.js, mandrill

I am creating summary eMails with recent activities that can be configured by the recipient. For that I am using Mandrill with the Handlebars templating syntax and `{{#each objects}}` passing in `objects`.

That all works fine. And I can use the `{{else}}` to display a message when that list is empty. (That event hasn't happened in the referenced period of time)

But now I want to give the user the option to never see a summary about that particular kind of event (no matter whether they exist or not). I tried using `{{#if objects}}` and simply not adding the parameter for that user. But that results in the entire block not showing up when the list is empty. But in that I case I just want to say something like "no recent activity in this category" which has been working fine so far.

**TL;DR:** How to differentiate between parameter not given and empty list given with handlebars.

Comment: You could use `{{#if objects.length}}` but it works only when objects is an array.

Comment: Also `{{#if objects}}` will be `true` if objects is passed and not falsy (`{}` and `[]` are not falsy), but `{{#each objects}}` will not output anything. Note that `{{else}}` statement could be used in `{{#each}}` as well, so you could do something like `{{#if objects}} {{#each objects}} ... {{else}} objects is empty {{/each}} {{else}} objects not passed {{/if}}`.

Comment: That is exactly what I a doing, but I always end up in the "objects not passed" block, eve when it is passed but empty.

Comment: Well, you're right. Look at [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zq4mwoeL/). Handlebars really determines empty array as false for some reason. [#if helper src](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/afe730e0594440dd17fdc43271fc4a7db19327f3/lib/handlebars/base.js#L177), [Utils.isEmpty src](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/ab96073c6bfde771dde1e8ff1aa7444192f7f6df/lib/handlebars/utils.js#L83). So, I think you should add some `objects.length` checks to your code.

Comment: Look at cheating with [#with helper](http://jsfiddle.net/zq4mwoeL/1/).